# how to read a number within a string using matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have a file with non standard format and i want to read specific parts of it, that consist of real or integer numbers.

```
str1='N.ELBETI.150.L10';

str2='KARDIA_3.150.L20';

str3='axeloos1.15.75.L20';

str4='florina2.6.3.L2.1';
```

i just want to store the numbers in the central part and at the end of each string, i.e.:

150 and 10 from str1, 150 and 20 from str2, 15.75 and 20 from str3, 6.3 and 2.1 from str4
i have tried several ways but i cannot. Can you help me ?

Comment: What, specifically, have you tried that isn't working, and in what way isn't it working?

Comment: sorry, regexp works for str1 but not forstr4

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the already posted, nice answer. Apply the following function to each string.

```
function [num1, num2] = extract_from_string(s)

num1 = str2num(s(find(s == '.',1,'first')+1:find(s == 'L',1,'first')-2));
num2 = str2num(s(find(s == 'L',1,'first')+1:end));

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp` like this:

To obtain the first number:

```
str1(regexp(str1,'\.\d')+1:regexp(str1,'L\d')-2)
```

To obtain the last number:

```
str1(regexp(str1,'L\d')+1:end)
```

These commands also work for the other strings

Comment: in both cases i get an answer: Empty string: 1-by-0

Comment: I don't know why you get an empty string. Try the other strings and remember to replace `str1` to `str2`/`str3`/`str4` in every part od the command (the first command has 3 `str1`

Comment: thanks, u r right! can you tell me how to build regexp to get the last three characters ('L10' in str1)

Comment: remove the `+1`: `str1(regexp(str1,'L\d'):end)`

Comment: and how to get the first characters (i.e. 'florina2') in str4 ?

Comment: `str4(1:regexp(str4,'\.\d')-1)`. My recommendation: execute every one of the `regexp` instructions above and try to discover what each one does.  See the help for `regexp` to see why it works.

Comment: thank you once again for yesterday answer. I found another problematic record in my input file: 'ROUF.22.T255.1' Is it possible to change the regexp command str1(regexp(str1,'L\d')+1:end) so as to read 'T255.1' without using "L" but any other letter ?

Comment: Yes it's possible but try to find out how by yourself. Read how regexp works and the use it to find letter+digit combinations in a string and then extracting the number you need.